# ClamAv Installation problem Error ERROR: initgroups() failed

Tags: clamav

I get the following error installing VlamAc on my Ubuntu Server 14.04:

```
ERROR: initgroups() failed. when starting ClamAv Daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

This error has been known to appear sometimes when clamav-daemon loads incorrectly. I suspect that you have managed to install clamav but it was unable to successfully start the daemon after installation. There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clamav/+bug/579661).

Try using the suggested workaround which is to run `sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start`.

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start` worked for me. Thanks